# Running ./pyspark fails to find local directories

Tags: pyspark, terminal

After installing Spark I am trying to run PySpark from the installation folder:

```
opt/spark/bin/pyspark
```

But I get the following errors:

```
opt/spark/bin/pyspark: line 24: /opt/spark/bin/load-spark-env.sh: No such file or directory
opt/spark/bin/pyspark: line 68: /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit: No such file or directory
opt/spark/bin/pyspark: line 68: exec: /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit: cannot execute: No such file or directory
```

Why is this happening when I can see these items in their respective directories? I'm also trying to get PySpark to run standalone as a command, but I'd imagine that I must solve the former problem first.

I am running this on  macOS.

Comment: How did you install it it? It seems like your installation is not correct or complete. Can you show the output of something like `tree -L 2 /opt/spark`?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that `SPARK_HOME` is not set. Try this:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
pyspark
```

FYI, it is strongly recommended to install software on mac OS using a package manager, like https://brew.sh

Answer (score 0):

This is the configuration:

```
export SPARK_HOME=<YOUR-PATH>/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python:$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

And if you are thinking to use notebook as well:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME:$PATH:~/.local/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```